# SSRS export to word pages per file limit

Tags: reporting-services, ms-word, export, report, limit

I need to export SSRS Report to Word in files with 30 pages. So if report contains 100 pages, I have to get 4 doc files(30, 30, 30 and 10 pages). How to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You should tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), just putting a requirement out as a "question" is a bit rude, at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this only programmatically using reporting services. For this you need:

1. Add additional parameter to your report which will indicate page
   range for output (i.e 1-30, 31-60...). And generate in report only
   that range of pages.
2. Generate wcf client for this service:

   > `http://[server name]/[reportserver path]/ReportExecution2005.asmx`

   for example:

   > `http://localhost/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx`
3. Using render method generate and export separately all pieces of
   report. you can read more about render method here: [msdn render
   method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsexecutionservice2005.reportexecutionservice.render%28SQL.90%29.aspx)